# SonicWall tz 215 with three LAN and three WAN

Tags: lan, sonicwall, wan

Due to some local needs, we need to have a maximum of 50 work stations per WAN. We would like to avoid having one SonicWall for each 50 PCs, as X0 is LAN and X1 is WAN. Is it possible to set X2 and X4 as LAN and X3, X5 as WAN?

The idea is to have something like this:

```
                 LAN   WAN
PC  1 to 50    -> X0 -> X1     

PC 51 to 100   -> X2 -> X3     

PC 101 to 150  -> X4 -> X5
```

ALl PCs are in the same LAN and see each other, but each group is directed to its respective gateway (X0 ip, X2 ip, X4 IP) and then it goes to its respective WAN, as we need an external server to detect PCs coming from different external IPs.

Can it be done?

Comment: do you have managed switches that allow vLAN tagging?

Comment: Hello Mike, I do, but we're redirecting by dhcp (by mac address) all pc's to each Sonicwall lap IP, so, no matter where in the building we move them, they always goes to the same gateway, that's why we're trying to do it with sonic interfaces as theoretically it should be possible. thanks!

Comment: Are you using different subnets or just different dhcp ranges on the same segment?

Comment: It's the same subnet, just different gateway assignation according to mac address, no matter where we connect the pc, it will be always redirected to th same gateway, so we ensure we don't pass our 50 pc's limite per public ip, but I would like habe the posibility of do it with all sonic interfaces to manage up to 150 pc's with one instead of having 3 sonics doing it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing static DHCP leases in the same subnet based on MAC I would recommend the following:

Use the X0 interface for your LAN and setup the DHCP server with the static leases.  To do this look under Network->DHCP Server and select 'Add Static' to set each lease.  Use X1, X2 and X3 as your WAN interfaces.

Under Network->Address Objects setup 3 objects as ranges for the IPs you wish to group. Such as X.X.X.1 to X.X.X.51 as IP Group 1.

Under Network->Routing setup static routes for outbound traffic for each range to use the desired gateway.  As an example:

SOURCE: IP Group 1 (address object for first IP group)
Destination:  All WAN IP
SERVICE: ANY
GATEWAY: X1 Default Gateway (This is the first ISP connection)
INTERFACE: X1
METRIC: 2
COMMENT: IP GROUP 1 TO ISP 1

I would also recommend checking 'Disable Route when the interface is disconnected' to allow for low-level failover if the interface gets unplugged.

This will allow you to use 1 LAN interface to accomplish what you wanted to setup.

Comment: Wow Mike, this solution is even better then the one I had in mind, I'm starting to implement it, thank you, I appreciate it so much!

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  This keeps as many interfaces open as possible.  I always try to keep a few open interfaces on our Sonicwalls in case of failure, labs or other needs.  That and you can't configure 2 interfaces on the same subnet, you'd have to have 3 separate subnets, one for each IP group, and special routing between them all if they needed to cross-talk, which is more of a headache than this.  Let me know how it turns out.